# Web Content Accessibility Guidelines?

Tags: html, accessibility

```
<span aria-describedby="" class="itemText">${itemText.itemName}</span>
```

I am not able to get value if i use `aria-describedby="${itemText.itemName}"`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please try to explain a bit more about your problem. Also, try and use the right tags so people who knows how to help get to your question.

Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you are trying to do something like this:

```
<span aria-describedby="${itemText.itemName}" class="itemText">${itemText.itemName}</span>
```

However, you do not need to add the span text to an `aria-describedby` attribute.

Screen readers will already read the text inside the span when the page loads in this case. Adding the `aria-describedby` attribute might actually cause some readers to read it twice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want screen reader to read description of element, But i tell you how aria-decribedby works.

aria-decribedby only contains the reference IDs if it is exist in same page aria describedby will never accept hard quoted string.

The aria-describedby attribute is used to indicate the IDs of the elements that describe the object. It is used to establish a relationship between widgets or groups and text that described them.

For Example :

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Landmark" aria-label="Landmark" aria-describedby="description">
  
<span id="description">This Field Only Accepts Alphabets</span>
```